# Python graph algorithm question , what is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, graph, collections, hashmap, queue

this is my first question ever here and I am trying to learn algorithms. Can you tell me please what is wrong with my code ?
Thanks for all kind responds.

Here is the code:

```
from collections import deque

graph ={}
graph["you"] = ["Mark", "Victoria", "Lovie", "Chi","John"]

def personIsSeller(name):
    return name[-1] == 'M'

def search(name):
    searchQueue = deque()
    searchQueue += graph[name]
    searched = []
    while searchQueue:
        person = searchQueue.popleft()
        if not person in searched:
            if personIsSeller(person):
                print(person, "is a mango-seller")
                return True
            else:
                searchQueue += graph[person]
                searched.append(person)
    return False

search("you")
```

Comment: Your `personIsSeller` is looking for the last letter in the name, and none of yours have capital "M"s

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, I changed the personIsSeller and it works right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
def personIsSeller(name):
    return name[0] == 'M
```

Well basically I changed the index of personIsSeller and it is working right now, I am a new one in community and thank you to @Andrew , he made me to change my approach to problem.